# MultiAutoCompleteTextField for Wicket

Tags: autocomplete, textarea, wicket, textfield

I need an `AutoCompleteTextField` for Wicket which can handle several autocomplete items separated by a comma.

Something like this: http://digitarald.de/project/autocompleter/1-1/showcase/delicious-tags/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve the problem by Ajax in wicket as the following

```
    TextArea partnersDB = new TextArea("partnersDB");
    String partnerKeeper;

    public String getPartnerKeeper() {
        return partnerKeeper;
    }
    public void setPartnerKeeper(String partnerKeeper) {
        this.partnerKeeper = partnerKeeper;
    }
    public String getMessageTypeKeeper() {
        return messageTypeKeeper;
    }
    public void setMessageTypeKeeper(String messageTypeKeeper) {
        this.messageTypeKeeper = messageTypeKeeper;
    }

    private void makePartnersAutoCompleter() {

        final List<String> allPartners = auditDAO.findAllPartnerIds();

        IAutoCompleteRenderer partnerRenderer = new AbstractAutoCompleteRenderer() {

            @Override
            protected String getTextValue(Object obj) {
                return getPartnerKeeper() + ((String) obj);
            }

            @Override
            protected void renderChoice(Object obj, Response r, String str) {
                r.write((String) obj);
            }

        };

        AutoCompleteBehavior autoCompleteBehavior = new AutoCompleteBehavior(partnerRenderer) {

            @Override
            protected Iterator<String> getChoices(String input) {
                int lastCommaIndex = input.lastIndexOf(';');
                String realInput = "";
                if (lastCommaIndex == -1) {
                    setPartnerKeeper("");
                    realInput = input;
                } else {
                    setPartnerKeeper(input.substring(0, lastCommaIndex) + ";");
                    realInput = input.substring(lastCommaIndex + 1);
                }

                List<String> completions = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < allPartners.size(); i++) {
                    String partner = allPartners.get(i);
                    if (partner.startsWith(realInput.toUpperCase()) || partner.startsWith(realInput.toLowerCase())) {
                        completions.add(partner + ";");
                    }
                }
                return completions.iterator();
            }

        };

                    partnersDB.add(autoCompleteBehavior);

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

[Wicket-extensions](http://www.wicketframework.org/wicket-extensions/index.html) provides autocomplete features.

Add an [`AutoCompleteBehavior`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/extensions/ajax/markup/html/autocomplete/AutoCompleteBehavior.html) to the `TextArea` in the same fashion [`AutoCompleteTextField`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.wicket/wicket-extensions/1.4.18/org/apache/wicket/extensions/ajax/markup/html/autocomplete/AutoCompleteTextField.java) uses it.

For instance:

```
TextArea t = new TextArea("area", new Model());
AutoCompleteBehavior<String> b = new AutoCompleteBehavior<String>(
            StringAutoCompleteRenderer.INSTANCE){
    @Override
    protected Iterator<String> getChoices(String input) {
        return getMyListElements().iterator();
    }
};
t.setOutputMarkupId(true);
t.add(b);
add(t);
```

If you are using Maven, just add the following dependency to start using wicket-extensions:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
    <version>${wicket.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

---

**EDIT** 
Seeing that the question is about Multi autocomplete textfields, like the one in [this example](http://digitarald.de/project/autocompleter/1-1/showcase/delicious-tags/), you might find the following link useful: [Wicket auto-complete text fields](http://www.databasesandlife.com/wicket-auto-complete-auto-suggest-text-fields/). There are a couple of components in there that seem to do just what you need.

You might also find [this discussion](http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/AutoCompleteTextField-autocomplete-multiple-fields-td1866624.html) and [this one](http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Auto-Complete-TextField-for-selecting-multiple-values-td1876107.html) in the Apache Wicket User list useful. You'll find a couple of links there to projects that seem to also have this component: [interwicket](http://code.google.com/p/interwicket/) and [WicketHub](http://code.google.com/p/wickethub/source/browse/#svn/trunk/wickethub/src/main/java/wickethub/web/components/autocompleter)

Comment: Thank you very much! The autocomplete works for the first option, but it doesn't work for the second one!

Comment: I think they need to be separated by a comma or sth. like that! :-?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean by _works for the first option but it doesn't work for the second one_. I've tried this in a 1.4 quickstart with a static List and it selects every element when clicking on it. The `getChoices(String input)` method is supposed to return a List (usually obtained applying `input` as a filter) of `<T>`, in this case, `String`. Can you elaborate on your problem/what are you trying to achieve/show some code?

Comment: Please post your current code into your question, so we can have a look at it.

Comment: I need multi Autocompleter like this: http://digitarald.de/project/autocompleter/1-1/showcase/delicious-tags/

Comment: that's why I have chosen a text area to enter more than one option, I mean after entering one, I need to enter another one, but with this solution I don't get autocompleter for the second one.

Comment: This is a completely different question. It was exceedingly unlikely that anyone understood that you were referring to this by reading the original question. Please edit the question to include this information.

Comment: I tried to use Wicket auto-complete text Field, but I get UnsupportedClassVersionError, it says: Bad version number in .class file, I'm using wicket 1.4.12, as it has been used in the jar file of auto-complete, do you have any idea?

Comment: If you're using the JAR file in [here](http://www.databasesandlife.com/wicket-auto-complete-auto-suggest-text-fields/), it seems that those classes are compiled with J2SE6.  You're running an earlier version of the JVM. I'd recommend to just import whatever sources you need into your project, and compile them along with your app. Probably the two Autocomplete components under `com\databasesandlife\util\wicket` (along with HTML).

Comment: tried both alternatives, It doesn't work! In case of import just required resources, I get NullPointerException in this line of MultipleValueAutoCompleteTextField: List<AutoCompleteOption> currentValues = new ArrayList<AutoCompleteOption>(currentIdsToTextField.length);

Answer (score 1):

Also see https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/tree/master/jdk-1.5-parent/autocomplete-tagit-parent

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answers and comments! I have some problems with each of the solutions, let's see the solution of github...which version of wicket I should use with it? I have made a project as the example and am trying to run it but have some problems with lib!

Comment: tagit doesn't seem to work with 1.6, or at least not out of the box.

Comment: Please create an issue or even better - a Pull Request.